# Invariant Violation: ViewPagerAndroid has been removed from React Native.'react-native-viewpager' instead of 'react-native'

Tags: react-native

when I implement Image-slider on my application using this example that time I have faced this error.

```
import React,{Component} from 'react'
    import {View,Text,TouchableOpacity, ViewPagerAndroid} from 'react-native'
    import Infoslider from 'react-native-infoslider'
     export default class example extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          data:[
              {
              title:"Hello World", 
              text:"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard",
              image: require('../Images/Group.png')}
             ]
        };
      }
      render() {
        return (
         <Infoslider 
            data={this.state.data} />
        );
      }
    }
```

[image: Error Like this]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should update the **react-native-swiper** module to **nightly**. Then, npm clear cache.
Please follow this:

> 1. cd android
> 2. ./gradlew clean
> 3. cd ..
> 4. **yarn remove react-native-swiper**
> 5. **yarn add react-native-swiper@nightly**
> 6. rm -rf node_modules
> 7. npm cache clean --force
> 8. npm install
> 9. react-native run-android

it will work. but if no, please restart system.

Comment: Please could you check this qs - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60927843/viewpager-of-react-native-gives-error-viewpagerandroid-has-been-removed-from

Answer (score 4):

I solve it by:

1. install this module: react-native-community / viewpager
2. Go to the file: node_modules\react-native-swiper\src\index.js, and :
   add this line: import ViewPager from '@react-native-community/viewpager';
   and remove this ViewPagerAndroid from the imports.
3. in the same file, go to the return function, and change ViewPagerAndroid to ViewPager

This works for me

Answer (score 2):

You can resolve this error by updating **react-native-swiper** to latest(**nightly**) and in case you don't want to update react-native-swiper then install **@react-native-community/viewpager** and remove import of ViewPagerAndroid from react-native and import it from @react-native-community/viewpager

Answer (score 1):

You need to first `yarn add @react-native-community/viewpager` or `npm i @react-native-community/viewpager` .

Thena after that remove ViewPagerAndroid from 'react-native' in imports and use

```
import ViewPager from '@react-native-community/viewpager';
```

hope it helps. feel free for doubts

Comment: A problem occurred configuring project ':@react-native-community_viewpager'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':@react-native-community_viewpager:classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1

Comment: are you using expo?

Comment: NO I was used npm

Comment: have you installed and checked documentation of https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-viewpager

Comment: Ok I will check

Comment: Every time I have to do changes in node modules After yarn install.
Any permanent solution !

Answer (score 0):

You needs to add @react-native-community/viewpager instead of importing ViewPagerAndroid from react-native.

Comment: I was not used expo. I was used npm

Comment: npm install @react-native-community/viewpager then if you are using react native link below 0.59 then use react-native link @react-native-community/viewpager
otherwise it automatically linked with packages.
now install pod.
 hope it will help you.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might also need to update your babel version and runtime in case you have the 'token not recognized' error.
Update the babel version following these steps:

npm install @babel/core@^7.9.0

npm install @babel/runtime@^7.9.2

npm install typescript@^3.8.3

rm -rf node_modules

npm install

npm start -- --reset-cache