# ViewPager of React Native gives error :: 'ViewPagerAndroid has been removed from React Native'

Tags: react-native, android-viewpager2

I am trying to use the View Pager on React Native and I am using the reference link for help
https://reactnativecode.com/create-viewpager-with-tab-title-dot-indicators/?unapproved=42387&moderation-hash=570c68d8ea5535b832994536ba239b28#comment-42387

When I use the code as it is and run, it gives an error -

```
ViewPagerAndroid has been removed from React Native. It can now be installed and imported from 'react-native-viewpager' instead of 'react-native'.
```

What is that I am missing ?

Answer (score 0):

```sh
yarn add @react-native-community/viewpager
```

Or

```sh
npm -i @react-native-community/viewpager --save
```

For linking use these command

```sh
react-native link @react-native-community/viewpager
```

In Newer versions of React Native ViewPager is not available, so you have to add it manually

then, you can import it like these

```js
import ViewPager from '@react-native-community/viewpager';
```

Comment: When possible, please make an effort to provide additional explanation instead of just code. Such answers tend to be more useful as they help members of the community and especially new developers better understand the reasoning of the solution, and can help prevent the need to address follow-up questions.

Comment: It seems that it is now deprecated. npmjs says: This library is no longer supported. Please use react-native-pager-view instead

Answer (score 0):

You have to notice:

if your **react native version** < 0.63 - you need install **react-native-tab-view** **2.x.x** version (the latest in this version is 2.16.0)

if >= 0.63 so install **3.x.x**

Maybe this is the reason