# I am getting error "ViewPagerAndroid has been removed from React Native" but i don't use it

Tags: android, react-native

i have a problem which i can't solve 1 month.

In the project, i don't use ViewPagerAndroid but i getting errors as i use it(photo in the description).

I even try to search 'ViewPagerAndroid' in the whole project but there are no results.

Interesting thing is that i get error when the focus is a screen witch use createMaterialTopTabNavigator.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ft8NA.png)

I don't use `ViewPagerAndroid`, this is happening every time when I navigate to the screen with `createMaterialTopTabNavigator`. I have this problem just on Android.

React Navigation 4

Do you have any idea?

[Dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ia402.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit the question to include a [*"Minimal, Reproducible, Example."*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly, because you don't have the needed [ViewPager](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-pager-view), you to add it in your project. (deprecated)

`"@react-native-community/viewpager"` library has been changed to `react-native-pager-view`. Here you can find more information, how to migrate `pager view` to the latest [version](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-pager-view/blob/master/MIGRATION.md)
.

**EDIT:**

In @Vladan Stevanovic's case helped this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59680596/invariant-violation-viewpagerandroid-has-been-removed-from-react-native-react).

Comment: I don't use that library, i don't have it in the project...

Comment: I updated my answer. Try that. You need an implementation that can handle your views.

Comment: Thanks, but where i should import this?

Comment: Try to follow along this steps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59680596/invariant-violation-viewpagerandroid-has-been-removed-from-react-native-react

Comment: Did it help you? Or do you have still problem with it?

Comment: I just solve it, i will describe it in the next post. Thank you, guys...

Comment: When i try to search 'ViewPagerAndroid' in the project there is no results. But when i open NodeModules and search library 'react-native-tab-view' and look in the file index.js there is 'ViewPagerAndroid' and it is imported from 'react-native'. I just change it with import ViewPager from '@react-native-community/viewpager' and everything is fine.

Comment: That's exactly what I described above in my solution ;) Feel free to tick it as correct. Glad you solved it.

Comment: The solution is your comment "Try to follow along this steps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59680596/invariant-violation-viewpagerandroid-has-been-removed-from-react-native-react".
Answer was given by @mohamed amine salah

Comment: Wonderful! Glad that you solved it! I don't want to bother you but Stackoverflow is made to be an encyclopedia, that's why I edit my answer. The though of SO is to have an answer on every question, to find the solution more easily when visiting the specific question. Happy coding! :)

Comment: Yes, thank you very much, i already voted but i don't know why we can not see it.

Comment: I upvoted your question. It seems to work. The hook or arrow up should work. Anyways, thanks! :)